# Two real serial ports connected by a virtual null-modem (in linux or windows)

Tags: linux, serial-port, socat

I have to connect to serial-to-usb in a null-modem configuration and I am trying to find a solution to connect them by a null-modem emulator. I found socat in linux but I didn't have luck to make them work. Anyone can suggest a way ?

```
sudo socat -b3000000 -d -d  -x file:/dev/ttyUSB1,nonblock,echo=0,raw,waitlock=/var/run/ttyUSB1.lock file:/dev/ttyUSB0,nonblock,echo=0,raw,waitlock=/var/run/ttyUSB0.lock
```

Comment: Perhaps you can add the help text to stdout to see what debug message you get?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
socat /dev/ttyUSB0 /dev/ttyUSB1
```

Then , you have to adjust bit rates, echo, etc.